# unable to connect to multiple database using Dancer::Plugin::Database

Tags: perl, yaml, dancer

I am using Dancer::Plugin::Database to connect with database from my dancer application. It works fine for single connection. When i tried for multiple connection i got error. How can i add multiple connection.

I added the following code in my config.yml file:

```
plugins:
        Database:
            connections:
                one:
                        driver: 'mysql'
                        database: 'employeedetails'
                        host: 'localhost'
                        port: 3306
                        username: 'remya'
                        password: 'remy@'
                        connection_check_threshold: 10
                        dbi_params:
                            RaiseError: 1
                            AutoCommit: 1
                        on_connect_do: ["SET NAMES 'utf8'", "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'" ]
                        log_queries: 1
                    two:
                        driver: 'mysql'
                        database: 'employeetree'
                        host: 'localhost'
                        port: 3306
                        username: 'remya'
                        password: 'remy@'
                        connection_check_threshold: 10
                        dbi_params:
                            RaiseError: 1
                            AutoCommit: 1
                        on_connect_do: ["SET NAMES 'utf8'", "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'" ]
                        log_queries: 1
```

Then i tried to connect with database using the following code :

```
my $dbh=database('one');
my $sth=$dbh->prepare("select * from table_name where id=?");
$sth->execute(1);
```

I got compilation error, "Unable to parse Configuration file"

Please suggest a solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

YAML requires consistent indentation for the keys of a hash.  Remove four spaces from before "two:" and it should parse.

Update: I see there's been some editing of indentation; going back to the original question produces a parsing error in a different place and shows a mixture of tabs and spaces being used; try to consistently use only tabs or only spaces.  You can test your file and find what line is producing the first error like so:

```
$ perl -we'use YAML::Syck; LoadFile "config.yml"'
Syck parser (line 19, column 16): syntax error at -e line 1, <> chunk 1.
```

Also make sure that your keys are all ending up in the right hash (the mixture of tabs and spaces seems to allow this coming out wrong but still parsing successfully) with:

```
perl -we'use YAML::Syck; use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys=$Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; print Dumper LoadFile "config.yml"'
```

Comment: The command line was `perl -0777we'use YAML::Syck; Load <>' config.yml`.  `-0777` on the command line is equivalent to `$/ = undef;` in code - it makes readline aka `<>` read whole files instead of lines.  Load() is a YAML function that parses the passed in yaml and returns a perl data structure (or gives an exception on a parse error)

Comment: @simbabque: but your question caused me to notice the LoadFile function, which is much easier :)

Comment: Thanks that problem solved.But now i am getting some other, while calling from browser i got this error.
Can't connect to data source 'dbi:' because I can't work out what driver to use (it doesn't seem to contain a 'dbi:driver:' prefix and the DBI_DRIVER env var is not set) at C:/Perl/site/lib/Dancer/Plugin/Database.pm line 205.                     my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn,$settings->{username}, $settings->{password}, $settings->{dbi_params});